# How to sum all word counts mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I already know how to count words in each row like this:

```
SELECT *,
IF(words <> '', (length(words)-length(replace(words,' ',''))+1), 0) AS words_count
FROM table
```

But now i need to SUM all counts from all rows.

How do i do it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the sum, use an aggregation query:

```
SELECT sum(if(words <> '', (length(words)-length(replace(words,' ',''))+1), 0)) AS words_count
FROM table;
```

EDIT:

If there are no rows, you can do this to avoid NULL values:

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(if(words <> '', (length(words)-length(replace(words,' ',''))+1), 0)), 0) AS words_count
FROM table;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff I had already tried that but in some cases i was not even geting 0 value. Now i know why. Because if there's no rows it returns NULL